# Can't generate PNG file from UIView snapshot

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

I want to generate a `.png` file from **UIView snapshot** but it's always `nil`. Could you give me a hint what's wrong with my code? I'm running Catalina 10.15.2 with Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13.3.

Here's my code's snippet:

```
extension UIView {

    fileprivate func snapShot(view: UIView) -> UIView {

        let snapshot = view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
        self.addSubview(snapshot!)
        return snapshot!
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var image: UIImage?
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    @IBAction func take(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let oneThird = CGRect(x: 0,
                              y: 0,
                          width: view.frame.size.width / 3,
                         height: view.frame.size.height / 3)

        let snap = view.snapShot(view: self.view)
        snap.frame = oneThird

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

            let png = snap.largeContentImage?.pngData()

            if let pngData = png {
                self.image = UIImage(data: pngData)
            }
            self.imageView = UIImageView(image: self.image)
        }
        print(self.view.subviews.indices)           // 0..<5

        print(imageView?.image as Any)              // NIL
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func getImageFromCurrentContext(bounds: CGRect? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds?.size ?? self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: bounds ?? self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        guard let currentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            return nil
        }

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return currentImage
    }
}
```

Pass the bounds if you would like 1/3 of the view or don't provide a bounds to get the image of the entire view.

Tested with sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private(set) var testView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private(set) var testImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.testImageView.image = self.testView.getImageFromCurrentContext()
        }
    }
}
```

I made `UIView` on the storyboard have a sample label inside it and changed the background color just to verify it is in fact creating the image. Then added an `UIImageView` under that. Connected the `UIView` to `testView` and the `UIImageView` to `testImageView`.

Comment: Or, better, use [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer).